# How to display in value in dropdown list in grideview on selected index change

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown down after postback i want to bind the second dropdown . i get the value but that is not displayed in the second  data:EntityDropDownList  .

```
 <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <data:EntityDropDownList runat="server" ID="dataServiceTypeId" Enabled="false"  DataSourceID="ServiceTypeIdServiceTypesDataSource"
                                                                DataTextField="ServiceCode" DataValueField="ServiceTypeId" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ServiceTypeID") %>'
                                                                AppendNullItem="true" Required="true" NullItemText="< Please Choose ...>" ErrorText="Required" />
                                                            <data:ServiceTypesDataSource ID="ServiceTypeIdServiceTypesDataSource" runat="server"
                                                                SelectMethod="GetAll" />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                                        <data:EntityDropDownList runat="server" ID="dataServiceTypeId"  DataSourceID="ServiceTypeIdServiceTypesDataSource"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="Service_SelectChange" AutoPostBack="true" 
                                                                DataTextField="ServiceCode" DataValueField="ServiceTypeId" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ServiceTypeID") %>'
                                                                AppendNullItem="true" Required="true" NullItemText="< Please Choose ...>" ErrorText="Required" />
                                                            <data:ServiceTypesDataSource ID="ServiceTypeIdServiceTypesDataSource" runat="server"
                                                              SelectMethod="GetAll" />

                                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Default">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDefault" Checked='<%# Bind("IsDefault") %>' Enabled="false"  runat="server" />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                                         <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDefault" Checked='<%# Bind("IsDefault") %>'    runat="server" />

                                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Plan">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>

                                                             <data:EntityDropDownList runat="server" ID="dataPricePlanId" Width="200px"  />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                                             <data:EntityDropDownList runat="server" ID="dataPricePlanId" Width="200px" AppendNullItem="true" NullItemText="< Please Choose ...>"  />

                                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

And my code is this

```
 protected void Service_SelectChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataPricePlanId.Items.Clear();

    string sValue = ((EntityDropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;

    int ServiceTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(sValue);
    TList<PricePlans> _pricePlans = _pricePlanService.GetByServiceTypeId(ServiceTypeId);
    _pricePlanService.DeepLoad(_pricePlans);
    if (_pricePlans.Count > 0)
    {
        dataPricePlanId.DataSource = _pricePlans;
        dataPricePlanId.DataTextField = "Description";
        dataPricePlanId.DataValueField = "PricePlanId";
        dataPricePlanId.DataBind();

    }
    else
    {
        dataPricePlanId.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("No Plan For this Service", "0"));


    }
}
```

i get value but my grid is not binding in second dropdownlist. Can you please help me .

Comment: _"i get the value but that is not displayed in the..."_ ?? What value do you get where and where is it not displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it in itemdatabound event

first find drowdown using e.item.findcontrol("dropdownname").
then bind it with datasource and then set selected value.

thanks